# How can I bind custom enum values to a @Html.CheckBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, enums

I have `enum` of 3 values. I want to bind the enum values to a `@Html.CheckBox`except the first one. How this can be acheived?

My `enum`-

```
public enum EType
{
    [EnumMember]
    UNKNOWN = 0,
    [EnumMember]
    Value1 = 1,
    [EnumMember]
    Value2 = 2
}
```

This is my `ViewBag` in controller which contains the enum values-

```
ViewBag.Enums = from Enum e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(EType))
                select new SelectListItem { Value = Convert.ToInt32(e).ToString(), Text =((EType)e).ToString() };
```

This is my Html-

```
<td>
@{
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Enums = ViewBag.Enums;
foreach (var item in Enums)
 {                                                                   
  @Html.CheckBox(item.Text, false, new { item.Value }) 
  <label>@item.Text</label><br />
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In View, try this

```
var enumList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(EType)).Cast<EType>().Skip(1);

@foreach (var optVal in enumList)
{ 
<label>
    @Html.CheckBox(optVal.ToString(), false, new { value = Convert.ToInt32(optVal).ToString()})
    @optVal

</label>
}
```

Comment: `Cast<EType>().Skip(1)` helped me. Thank you.